# batch file: assign decimal value to variable

Tags: windows, audio, batch-file

This script is run from within a directory of OGG files.

```
cd c:\dirWithOGG
for %%f in (*.ogg) do (
sox %%f %%f pad 0 "soxi -D %%f"
sox %%f %%f repeat 10
)
```

First time I've had to create a batch script, I thought it's going to easy.

```
soxi -D %%f
```

On it's own, the above returns a decimal value. For some reason, it's doesn't execute from within the script. **sox** and **soxi** are in a location added to **PATH**.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How is `"soxi -D %%f"` supposed to be run? Is it by `sox` or do you mean it to be run by the `cmd` shell and it's output be substituted as another argument to `sox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the output of `soxi -D %%f` as a command line parameter for `sox`, here's how you can do that:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.ogg) DO CALL :runsox "%%f"
GOTO :EOF

:runsox
soxi -D %1>tmpfile
SET /P decvalue=<tmpfile
sox %1 %1 pad 0 %decvalue%
sox %1 %1 repeat 10
```

As you can see, the commands inside the loop have been moved to a subroutine that the loop is calling now. Other than that, the output of `soxi` is redirected to a file, which then is read into a variable, which in turn is used to pass the value to `sox`.

It's actually because of the variable that I had to move the commands outside the loop. It would work incorrectly inside the loop unless delayed expansion was enabled and a different syntax was used to address the variable. I preferred it implemented as above, though.

Comment: Yes, output soxi -D %%f is a parameter for sox. script works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `for` requires the action to be specified on the same line. Try the following:

```
for %%f in (*.ogg) do sox %%f %%f pad 0 "soxi -D %%f" && sox %%f %%f repeat 10
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Basically, milowas's syntax is correct there. It's something different, probably something to do with `"soxi -D %%f"` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding the `FOR` in your head (or on paper):

```
FOR %%F IN (*.ogg) DO (
  sox %%F %%F pad 0 "soxi -D %%F"
  sox %%F %%F repeat 10
)
```

If you have one `.ogg` file, say `foo.ogg`, then the `FOR` loop would cause the following two statements to be executed.

```
sox foo.ogg foo.ogg pad 0 "soxi -D foo.ogg"
sox foo.ogg foo.ogg repeat 10
```

I don't think that the first line is going to do what you expect.  It will run `sox` and pass the remainder of the line as parameters.  It will not execute `soxi -D foo.ogg` and replace it with its output.  DOS doesn't work this way at all.  Try something like:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
FOR %%F IN (*.ogg) DO (
  FOR /F %%N IN ('soxi -D %%F') DO (
    sox %%F %%F pad 0 "%%N"
    sox %%F %%F repeat 10
  )
)
ENDLOCAL
```

That might work.  I don't have access to a DOS box so I might have the inner `FOR` syntax wrong.  You may have to specify the subcommand with backticks or double quotes.  The enhanced version of the `FOR` loop requires command extensions to be enabled IIRC.  Try typing `FOR /?` at the command prompt or give http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm a read for more information.